# How to make Google Maps scroll properly inside Scroll View?

Tags: android, google-maps, scrollview, android-scrollview

I have a fragment which holds a map(view) that is inside a scroll view of my layout.

Problem is that map doesn't scroll properly(difficult to scroll) up or down. The scroll view seems to be interfering with the vertical scrolling of the map. It scrolls fine(smoothly) horizontally just not vertically.

How can I fix this?

**MY XML Layout:**

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewContactEmail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/contactEmailIcon"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_contactemail" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewContactEmail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageViewContactEmail"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageViewContactEmail"
                android:layout_marginEnd="-50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="255dp"
                android:text="@string/contactEmail"
                android:textColor="#bdbdbd" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewContactEmailLink"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="61dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="61dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="275dp"
                android:text="@string/emailNDTC"
                android:textColor="#2196F3" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewContactLine"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textViewContactEmailLink"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/contactLine"
                android:src="@drawable/line" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewContactPhone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewContactLine"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/contactPhoneIcon"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_contactphone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewContactPhone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageViewContactEmail"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageViewContactEmail"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewContactLine"
                android:layout_marginEnd="-50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                android:text="@string/contactPhone"
                android:textColor="#bdbdbd" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewContactPhoneLink"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewContactLine"
                android:layout_marginLeft="61dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="61dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
                android:text="@string/phoneNDTC"
                android:textColor="#2196F3" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewContactLine2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textViewContactPhoneLink"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/contactLine2"
                android:src="@drawable/line" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewContactLocationPin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewContactLine2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/locationPinIcon"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_contactlocation" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewContactLocationPin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewContactLine2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="@string/contactAddress"
                android:textColor="#bdbdbd" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewContactStreetAddress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textViewContactLocationPin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:text="@string/ndtcStreetAddress"
                android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/map_container"
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textViewContactStreetAddress"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                tools:context=".ContactsActivity">

                <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:id="@+id/map"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    tools:context="pi.com.ndtc.MapsActivity" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewContactLine3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/map_container"
                android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/contactLine3"
                android:src="@drawable/line" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewContactTitleSocial"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewContactLine3"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/contactTitleSocial"
                android:textColor="#bdbdbd" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

**My Activity:**

```
    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));


    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use google map inside scrollview! Because MapView is already a scrolling layout!

Comment: But if I don't put it inside of the scrollview how will it scroll along with my other contents?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add a transparent ImageView that fits the mapFragment:

```
           <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imagetrans"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mapfragment"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/mapfragment"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/mapfragment"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/mapfragment"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mapfragment"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/mapfragment"
            android:src="@color/transparent"/>
```

And then, when the user is touching it, disallow the scrollView:

```
final ScrollView scroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);
ImageView transparent = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagetrans);

transparent.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                    scroll.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    // Disable touch on transparent view
                    return false;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                    scroll.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    return true;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    scroll.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    return false;

                default:
                    return true;
            }
        }
    });
```

This way, only when the user touches the ImageView, the map will respond to touching events. The rest of the time, the ScrollView will respond.

Comment: What is "transparent" in transparent.setOnTouchListener?

Comment: transparent is the transparent ImageView, obviously. You can initialize it the same way you initialize any other component: ImageView transparent=findViewById(R.id.imagetrans). And scroll...is the scrollview. You need a reference to it to be able to disallow the scrolling. You reference it the same way you do with anything else: ScrollView scroll=findViewById(R.id.scroll)

Comment: Yeah I'm flustered due to being tired, I fixed that immediately after asking. Appreciate it though and marked your answer as correct. The image view combined with the listener did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

For google map v2, follow the solution is this tutorial

http://www.londatiga.net/it/programming/android/how-to-make-android-map-scrollable-inside-a-scrollview-layout/

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment cannot be cast to pi.com.mymapsapplication.WorkaroundMapFragment

Comment: I tried that just now and it gave me the above error at this line: mMap = ((WorkaroundMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

Comment: please change your xml file 
     <fragment
        android:tag="fragment_map"
       android:id="@+id/fragment_map"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="175dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
       class="your.package.name.WorkaroundMapFragment"/>