# How to pinch to zoom in a WebView inside ScrollView?

Tags: android, webview, scrollview

How to pinch to zoom in a WebView inside ScrollView?

I know I should have avoided using WebView inside a ScrollView but I have to. I have the following layout:

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativebelowscroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/jobcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
            </WebView>
            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/jobcontent"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:adSize="BANNER"
                app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
                <!--The following should be shown on ad failed to load -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/dimage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/jobcontent"
                android:background="#367AB8"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:visibility="visible">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/dimage2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/banner_left"
                    android:visibility="visible" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/dimage3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:src="@drawable/banner_right"
                    android:visibility="visible" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Its working good but the zoom in gesture having some problems as it is inside a ScrollView. I have looked other same questions but they all suggests to remove ScrollView but I cant in this particular case. I have a adview just below WebView so when user scrolls it scrolls all the way to adview but if I dont use ScrollView the scroll ends till the WebView gets its end on scroll. It doesn't scroll below WebView to show that adview. So in this case the ScrollView is needed and can't be removed. If I use this layout than I can pinch zoom but can't scroll below WebView content to show adview.

```
    <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/jobcontent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
    </WebView>
                <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                    android:id="@+id/adView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/jobcontent"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:adSize="BANNER"
                    app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/dimage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/jobcontent"
                    android:background="#367AB8"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:visibility="visible">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/dimage2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="left|center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/banner_left"
                        android:visibility="visible" />
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/dimage3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:src="@drawable/banner_right"
                        android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Is there any possibility to show pinch to zoom in my situation or get the second layout scroll working till adview?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117198/how-to-make-google-maps-scroll-properly-inside-scroll-view/33117866#33117866

Comment: Thanks @Fustigador . I had a quick look here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent  So allowing intercepting touch events only to MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL and blocking all others will be the solution for pinch to zoom than?

Comment: You have also to disallow the ScrollView to intercept the motion event when the webview is intercepting it, but yes, its basically that.

Comment: @M.Monoo did you manage to solve this?